# alias command with an option

Tags: shell, sed, alias

I am trying to alias a command with an option. Basically, I have a command `my_tool -version` which returns:

> TOOL : my_tool  v1.2.3.4

In a new version of the tool, `my_tool` is a link to `my_tool_1`, and 
`my_tool -version` returns:

> TOOL : my_tool_1  v1.2.3.5

For backward compatibility reasons this is awful, and I would like to have an alias on the global command `my_tool -version` which would achieve :

```
my_tool_1 -version | sed 's/my_tool_1/my_tool/'
```

I tried to alias the command `my_tool -version`, but it does not want to handle the second argument.
Would anyone have any idea on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score -1):

try this;

```
echo "$(my_tool_1 -version 2>&1)" | sed 's/my_tool_1/my_tool/'
```

`"2>&1"` simply points everything sent to stderr, to stdout instead.

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.